# Jquery scroll to link with name

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have the following HTML

```
<div class="anchors">
  <a href="#one">One</a>
  <a href="#two">Two</a>
  <a href="#three">Three</a>
</div>

<a name="one"></a>
<a name="two"></a>
<a name="three"></a>
```

When clicking an anchor link, I want to scroll to the position of the corresponding `<a>` tag. For example if I click `<a href="#two">Two</a>` the window should scroll to `<a name="two"></a>`

I tried the following js:

```
    $(".anchors a").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var $this = $(this),
      anchor = $this.attr('href').replace('#', ''),
      dest = $("a[name='" + anchor + "']");
      $('html,body').animate( { scrollTop: dest.offsetTop }, 'fast' );
    });
```

Nothing happens on click..

Note: The HTML cannot be modified, just the JS.

```js
$(".anchors a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this),
    anchor = $this.attr('href').replace('#', ''),
    dest = $("a[name='" + anchor + "']");
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: dest.offsetTop
  }, 'fast');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="anchors">
  <a href="#one">One</a>
  <a href="#two">Two</a>
  <a href="#three">Three</a>
</div>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<a name="one">ONE</a>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<a name="two">TWO</a>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<a name="three">THREE</a>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
```

Comment: It's `offset().top`, not `offsetTop`. See the duplicate for more information

Comment: Side note : The <a> name attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use the id attribute instead.

Comment: @wlarcheveque _Note: The HTML cannot be modified, just the JS._

Comment: Please note I made you a snippet. It is much easier to test and answer when you provide a [mcve]